# SQL Server - Join results of one query to first matching result from second query

Tags: sql-server

I want to join the results of paycheck_detail query with the results of timesheet query, joining on employeeId. Each employee will have one paycheck record per pay period that needs to join to the first matching timesheet record in order to fill a pdf form.

**Query 1**

```sql
SELECT employeeId, workday, hours FROM timesheet WHERE weekEndingDate = '2019-01-19'
  employeeId    workday     hours     
 ------------ ------------ -------   
          25   2019-01-18    2.68       
          25   2019-01-18    4.05     
          25   2019-01-18    2.75     
          29   2019-01-18    3.25      
          29   2019-01-18       4      
          29   2019-01-18    2.75
```

**Query 2**

```sql
SELECT * FROM paycheck_detail WHERE weekEndingDate = '2019-01-19' 

  employeeId   weekendingdate   fica    federal   local   state   checkNumber  
 ------------ ---------------- ------- --------- ------- ------- ------------- 
          29   2019-01-19       26.06     19.00    3.41   10.46         13325  
          25   2019-01-19       47.00     19.20    5.60   11.20         13326
```

**Desired result**

```
  employeeId    workday     hours   fica    federal   local   state   checkNumber     
 ------------ ------------ ------- ------- --------- ------- ------- ------------- -- 
          25   2019-01-18    2.68   47.00     19.20    5.60   11.20         13326     
          25   2019-01-18    4.05                                                     
          25   2019-01-18    2.75                                                     
          29   2019-01-18    3.25   26.06     19.00    3.41   10.46         13325     
          29   2019-01-18       4                                                     
          29   2019-01-18    2.75
```

Comment: It makes no sense that "SELECT * FROM timesheet" should return a resultset with only employeeId,workday,hours (no weekEndingDate) when the WHERE clause implies the existence of such a column

Comment: How can Query 1 run? It doesn't even a column called `weekEndingDate`

Comment: That is correct. I didn't show all the columns to avoid clutter but I edited the question now.